# How do you equally space out elements in a Row?

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

```
Row{
    width: parent.width
    spacing: ????
    Checkbox{}
    Checkbox{}
    Checkbox{}
    Checkbox{}
}
```

So just to be clear, the checkboxes should be spaced in such a manner that however wide the row is, it will expand or compress the spacing in accordance to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to set `width: parent.width/4` for each of the checkboxes.  If you want to keep the checkbox width set at some known value, you could instead set `spacing: (parent.width - 4 * checkboxwidth)/3` on the Row.  Note that this will cause the elements to overlap when the parent is narrow.

If you're targeting Qt 5.1 or higher, you may want a [RowLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html).  I'm still on 5.0, though, so I can't help you there.

Yet another way to do this would to be to put each CheckBox in an Item.  Each Item would have `width: parent.width/4`, and each CheckBox would have `anchors.centerIn: parent`.  This would give a half-width margin on the far left and far right, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: On 5.3 actually... RowLayout; why didn't I see that? Anyways what I ended up doing is setting the checkbox width manually to units.gu(4), then for spacing: (row.width - units.gu(4[gu]*4[checkboxes]))/3[spaces]. Worked perfectly.